# Scala type mismatch [scala]

Tags: scala

I have the following function

```
def weight(Actors:RDD[(String,Int)],name:String,count:Int):Float={
    val count1=Actors.lookup(name)
    val i_count=if (!count1.isEmpty) count1(0) else 0
    val edge=if (i_count!=0) (count.toFloat/i_count.toFloat) else 0.0   
}
```

and I get the following error

```
 <console>:229: error: type mismatch;
 found   : Unit
 required: Float
       }
```

Is it caused by divide 0 error?
How to solve that problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `weight` function is not returning anything but `Float` is defined as a return type.

Replacing the final line

```
val edge=if (i_count!=0) (count.toFloat/i_count.toFloat) else 0.0
```

by

```
if (i_count!=0) (count.toFloat/i_count.toFloat) else 0F
```

should resolve your issue

Answer (score 0):

This error means your are `return` `Unit` for `weight` method, but 
`def weight(Actors:RDD[(String,Int)],name:String,count:Int):Float`  is expecting `return Float` value of this method, so this compile error is **throwed**.

Solution:

@Ramesh Maharjan has provided a way to fix this. but also you can try **pattern match** in **Scala**, like:

```
i_count match {
  case 0 => 0.0F
  case _=> count.toFloat/i_count.toFloat
}
```

Answer (score 0):

No, it's not related to division-by-zero.  Defining a `val` as the last line in your function will be treated as returning type `Unit`.  Changing it to the following will fulfill the `Float` return type you declared for the function:

```
if (i_count != 0) (count.toFloat / i_count.toFloat) else 0.toFloat
```